# Plot value of resistor in electrothermal circuit

Tags: spice

I want to plot the "equivalent" value of a resistor that uses electrothermal model

```
* Dummy SPICE netlist
R1 net1 net2 1 TC = -0.01
```

I can do it with a .defwave, but this is prone to numerical errors if V or I are small, close to 0.

```
* Dummy SPICE netlist
R1 net1 net2 1 TC = -0.01
.defwave resistor=V(net1,net2)/I(R1)
```

But how to do it with an `.extract` ?

```
* Dummy SPICE netlist
R1 net1 net2 1 TC = -0.01
.extract label=resistor2 unit=Ohm yval(R1) ! <- yval(??)
```

Currently it doesn't work, as R1 seems to be understand as a parameter, and not the resistor device

Comment: What spice package are you using?

Comment: I used the analog spice simulator eldo. Not sure of what a package is imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it using the E operator (eval operator)  in a `.plot`

```
.plot tran E(R1,R)
```

The `E(INST,PARAM)` evaluates (E[VAL]) the parameters of the requested instance/device and plots it